# If condition in Objective function.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research

I am new to optimization problems. I'm solving an integer programming problem, but I have a problem with the objective function. The question states that if the Quantity allocated in a store (**Q**) is greater than the required quantity (**RQ**), the penalty is **P1** and if the Quantity allocated is less than **RQ**, the penalty is **P2**. How can I frame the objective function for this since it involves conditional logic?

Comment: what happens if the $Q=RQ$?

Comment: No penalty since (Q-RQ)=0

Answer (score 3):

Introduce binary variables $x_1$ and $x_2$, and impose linear big-M constraints
\begin{align}
Q - RQ &\le M_1 x_1 \tag1 \\
RQ - Q &\le M_2 x_2 \tag2 \\
\end{align}
Here, $M_1$ is a small constant upper bound on $Q-RQ$, and $M_2$ is a small constant upper bound on $RQ-Q$.
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $Q>RQ \implies x_1=1$.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces $Q<RQ \implies x_2=1$.
Now minimize $P_1 x_1 +P_2 x_2$.